# Android MediaPlayer stuck in prepare()

Tags: android, media-player

I'm facing a serious problem with the Media Player(MP) being stuck at the `prepare()` method. 
My app runs `prepare()` in an `AsyncTask` to avoid blocking the UI, since the sources are from the web. There are several 'play' buttons that the user can click at any time, so I added the `prepare()` inside a synchronized method to better control the state of the MP. My app also call a `release()` onPause to free the used resources.

Thing is, I noticed that if `release()` is called while preparing, `prepare()` never returns, and so I'm stuck inside a synchronized method. The worst of it is that the `AsyncTask` thread is in a deadlock, and every time that the user click on play in that state another thread is wasted since it keeps waiting to acquire the monitor that is in possesion of the never-returning `prepare()`. Soon all my `AsyncTasks` threads are wasted and since I use them extensively, my app stops working.

So my question is: do anyone has an idea of how overcoming this problem? I'm seriously thinking of redoing all my work with the MediaPlayer, but I need to know the best way to handle situations like this one beforehand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `prepareAsync()` instead. And you won't need `AsyncTask` just for the sake of `MediaPlayer` preparation.

Comment: I thought of that, but I'm not quit sure that it would solve the problem at hand. The MediaPlayer docs says that "It is important to note that the Preparing state is a transient state, and the behavior of calling any method with side effect while a MediaPlayer object is in the Preparing state is undefined." So the problem would remain, I would call release() in the 'preparing' state, and the outcome is undefined. I suspect that inside my synchronous prepare(), the MediaPlayer shifts to this 'preparing' state and that results in the erros that I'm receiving.

Comment: According to diagram and state table you can call `release()` from any state. Give it a go. I think you're just facing multithreading related bug. And excluding multiple threads should "fix" it.

Comment: It does say that I can call release() at any time, but even so I'm facing the problem of being stuck if I call this inside a prepare(). This shouldn't happen and is a bug in Android IMO.

Comment: No, I was saying that even though the docs says that I can call `release()` at any time, I'm facing the original problem of being stuck inside a `prepare()`. I don't think that is a bad idea using `prepareAsync()`, but I do believe that there should exist a way of making it work correctly with `prepare()`.

Comment: This is the proper solution. The solution you marked as an answer is merely working around the functionality already provided to you by MediaPlayer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using `Asyntasks` or `prepareAsync()` for that matter is that it doesn't automatically switch the `MediaPlayer's` state to prepared. You would think it does, but for some reason it doesn't. I got stuck with this same problem for a few days until someone suggested me to implement the `OnPreparedListener`, and use that to use my `MediaPlayer`.

Adding it is quite simple.

First, implement the listener in your class: (I'm using this for a Service so yours will look slightly different.)

```
public class MusicService extends Service implements OnPreparedListener
```

Next, in your play / prepare statement, use `prepareAsync`, and set the listener.

```
mp.prepareAsync();
mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
```

Next, add the `onPrepared` method and add your starting code:

```
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaplayer) {
        // We now have buffered enough to be able to play
        mp.start();
    }
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers, but I fixed this not using the prepareAsync() as was mentioned in previous answers. I think that if a synchronous method of preparing was made available, there should be a way of making it work correctly.

The fix, although not elegant IMO, is simple: avoid calling release() inside a prepare(). Although the state diagram in the Media Player docs says that release() can be called in any state, experimentation proved that calling it inside a prepare() (presumably in the 'Preparing' state) will hang your app. So I added a check to see if the MP is in this state and I am now avoding calling release() if it is. I needed to add a boolean in my code to check this, since there is no isPreparing() method in the MP.

I'm confident that this shouldn't happen and is a bug in Android itself. As can be seen in the comments, there is a contradiction in the docs: it says that release() can be called at any state, but also says that calling any state changing commands while in the Preparing state has an undefined outcome. Hope that this will help other people.

Answer (score 0):

My Media Player was stuck in Prepare because I was using non-secure URLs, (HTTP instead of HTTPS)

I had to add the following in the android manifest.

```
<application
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ...
</application>
```