# MediaPlayer broken url issue

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I use simple MediaPlayer in my project for listening to my audio.

My app freezes (crashes after a while) if the audio link is broken or incorrect.

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
try {
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource("my audio link");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Thank you for your helping.

Update:

logcat

```
2019-12-15 06:00:04.090 7692-7692/com.swipe.app W/MediaPlayer: Use of stream types is deprecated for operations other than volume control
2019-12-15 06:00:04.090 7692-7692/com.swipe.app W/MediaPlayer: See the documentation of setAudioStreamType() for what to use instead with android.media.AudioAttributes to qualify your playback use case
2019-12-15 06:00:34.824 7692-7806/com.swipe.app E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)
2019-12-15 06:00:34.825 7692-7692/com.swipe.app W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare(Native Method)
2019-12-15 06:00:34.825 7692-7692/com.swipe.app W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(MediaPlayer.java:1274)
2019-12-15 06:00:34.827 7692-7692/com.swipe.app E/MediaPlayerNative: start called in state 0, mPlayer(0xc68284a0)
2019-12-15 06:00:34.827 7692-7692/com.swipe.app E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
2019-12-15 06:00:34.836 7692-7692/com.swipe.app E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
```

Comment: Please share the logcat file .

Comment: I have updated my question @ManujaJayawardana

Comment: waiting for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Replace

```
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
```

With following code

```
final AudioAttributes audioAttributes =new AudioAttributes
            .Builder()
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
            .build();
mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes);
```

You can change the AudioAttributes type into type you wanted. See Documentation.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioAttributes

Reason is setAudioStreamType is depreciated method. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer

Comment: my app freezes when I use 404 link, sorry for my bad English.

Comment: What do you mean by 404 link ? do you mean by not available link ?
Can you share the audio url ? or let us know what type of media you wanted to play ? ( eg internal music , online music ? )

Comment: Yes I mean not available link. My app freezes if my link not avaible or offline or broken.

Comment: @farfar009 please try this methods. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511210/android-mediaplayer-stuck-in-prepare

Comment: I did not understand, which method should I use?

Comment: Thanks for your help I tried Sander van't Veer's answer and problem solved.

Comment: Ok Glad that i could help. if this post helps you please upvote it. Thank you.